# Unrecognised escape sequence when publishing to file system | ASP Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to publish asp.net core mvc app to file system but it shows an error occurred " Unrecognized escape sequence. (48)" with 
**"DefaultConnection" string**

I am using mvc web-app template with **"Individual User Accounts"** Authentication with no changes at all.

[image]

PS: I have successfully uploaded to azure but can't make it work for IIS

Answer (score 0):

The escape sequence is probably referring to the two back slashes in the string.  Tough to say because your screenshot doesn't include the entire file.  I would try changing it to this:

`Server=(localdb)\mssqlocaldb`